# Using association when the class does not call on the object's methods

Tags: class, associations, uml

Is it correct to show association between two classes when the class which has the reference to the second class actually does not call on any of its(second class's) methods but still keeps the second class's object as a reference to pass as parameters to methods of other classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If class `A` only uses class `B` to pass it around, I would create a `<<dependency>>` link instead of an association link between the classes.